# DiscordJS v14 fetching server owner but cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the owner ID/tag on Discord.JS v14 after adding the bot to the server using this method

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'guildCreate',
  execute: async (guild, client) => {
    try {
      const ownerId = guild.ownerId
      const owner = guild.members.cache.get(ownerId);
      console.log(owner.user.tag)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

but then I get this error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')**

Comment: Just asking to be sure, enabled intents for guild members? What happens if you just output `owner` using `console.log(owner)`, do you get the member object?

Comment: I got undefined in console, and yes i do have guild and guildmembers intents enabled

Comment: Can you show your event handler file?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the owner as a `GuildMember` using `<Guild>.fetchOwner()` (which returns a Promise that resolves to a `GuildMember` object). ex.

```js
let owner = await guild.fetchOwner();
console.log(owner.id, owner.tag);
```